# Is there a philosophy which argues that nothing exists?

Tags: history-of-philosophy

Is or was there a philosophy which examines a hypothesis that in fact nothing "exists" except maybe questions?

I know there are philosophies that state that reality is a simulation etc. but I mean that not even a simulation exists. The only "things" that exist are the questions we ask.

Comment: "Nihilism" might be the closest well-explored philosophical position that seems like it might answer to the spirit of these requirements. I might suggest getting oriented with SEP entries like [Moral Skepticism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/skepticism-moral/) and [Nothingness](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nothingness/).

Comment: If "the questions we ask" we ask exist, mustn't there also be an *asker*?

Comment: It really depends on your definition of existence.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could be more precise about what you mean when you write `Is there a philosophy which [argues that] nothing exists?`. There are two mutually exclusive meanings to it: Do you mean the thesis that non-existence exists in some sense, e.g. that [nonexistent (fictional) objects exist](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nonexistent-objects) or, to the contrary that, with Parmenides, [what is not, cannot exist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parmenides#The_Way_of_Truth)? (I'd think you mean the latter, but you could reassure us.)

Comment: Also, what is a bit puzzling about your question is the apparent [performative contradiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performative_contradiction) in your question, as noted by @stoicfury.

Comment: First of all, it would be better to phrase the question "Is there a philosophical position..." and not "...a philosophy...". There is only philosophy, just as there is only physics within which exist a number of varying positions. It's not an ideology or some other relativist nonsense, in other words. Concerning your question, I would say "no" for rather obvious reasons. Philosophy presupposes an object of study, although some debate exists over what exactly that object is.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_why_there_is_anything_at_all

Comment: I have never come across anyone suggesting such a thing. But as has been pointed out, it all depends what you mean by 'exists'. Many philosophers argue that things do not exist in the way we usually think they do, and it may be the most popular view. ,. .  .

Answer (score 3):

> We join spokes together in a wheel,
>       but it is the center hole
>       that makes the wagon move.
>
> We shape clay into a pot,
>       but it is the emptiness inside
>       that holds whatever we want.
>
> We hammer wood for a house,
>       but it is the inner space
>       that makes it livable.
>
> We work with being,
>       but non-being is what we use.
>
> – Tao Te Ching, Stephen Mitchell Translation

I may have misunderstood it. I'm talking about philosophy where nothingness has a central role.

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised this wasn't mentioned before, at least not explicitly (it was implicitly pointed out in one of the comments, as this view is considered to be nihilistic):

> “**Nothing exists**; even if something exists, nothing can be known about it; and even if something can be known about it, knowledge about it can't be communicated to others.” - [Gorgias](http://www.iep.utm.edu/gorgias/)

One must be careful though:

> This argument has led some to label Gorgias as either an ontological skeptic or a nihilist (one who believes nothing exists, or that the world is incomprehensible, and that the concept of truth is fictitious). But **it can also be interpreted as an assertion that it is logos and logos alone which is the proper object of our inquiries**, since it is the only thing we can really know. On Nature is sometimes seen as a refutation of pre-Socratic essentialist philosophy (McComiskey 37). (source: [IEP](http://www.iep.utm.edu/gorgias/#SH2a))

As many have said before me here, I think the question is self-defeating. You have the thought (i.e. *it exists)* to ask yourself whether *there is* a philosophy that asks whether nothing exist. The existence of the thought means that something exists and would famously give rise to Descartes' new foundation of all knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

That nothing exists is posited in [medieval ontology](https://vdocuments.mx/the-distinction-between-essentia-and-existentia-in-scholasticism.html)

> In this attempt mysticism arrives at a peculiar speculation, peculiar
>   because it transforms the idea of essence in general, which is an
>   ontological determination of a being, the essentia entis, into a being
>   and makes the ontological ground of a being, its possibility, its
>   essence, into what is properly actual.

This mystical theology appears to be saying, (amongst other things), that the essence of nothing does not require production to become actual.  For example, whereas the concept (res essentia) of any other thing, such as a table, requires the making of the thing to become an *actual* thing (res existentia), 'nothing' does not require anything further to reify its concept.  It uniquely qualifies as actual nothing by itself.

Comment: Interesting point about 'Nothing' and I hadn't though of it myself. The ontological claim would be that all that exists is created, and all that is created has no independent existence but depends on what is truly real. The word 'God' may be used for this 'Nothing' that lies beyond all diversity, but this language would be optional. It would be impossible for there to ever be a true Nothing, but the Nothing of mysticism is also Everything, Roughly speaking, Everything would be Nothing but Nothing would not be Nothing.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood something: the Nothing of mysticism

Comment: Degen - Perhaps you're right but I'd take some convincing. Check out Nagarjuna's proof that nothing really exists or ever happens.

Comment: @PeterJ You mean Nagarjuna thinks it's all just cosmic debris? In contrast the Thomists are addressing the concept of nothing as a kind of empty set: the base concept before any predicates are added, such as colour, purpose or composition.  Then, in effect, the mystics seem to say that, uniquely, Nothing does not require production to properly exist.  Interesting to try to fuse this with Nagarjuna's debris of obliteration, but it seems clear that the debris does materially exist, even if it means nothing, (which I presume is what Nagarjuna is driving at).

Comment: Nagarjuna is not at odds with the Thomists. He proves that there is no 'cosmic debris'. The world of multiplicity would reduce to Unity. There would be no material existence. This is a metaphysical or fundamental view and does not deny the evidence of our senses. Rather, it denies our usual interpretation of this evidence. It would not imply that existence is meaningless but that it is not fundamental or truly real, such that its meaning derives from what is fundamental.and truly real. In this way he solves all metaphysical  problems.

Answer (score 0):

The statement "X exists" is meaningless without first defining "existence".

For nothing to "exist", that would mean that you and everything you know falls outside of "existence".

Any definition of the word "existence" where everything you know would not "exist" would be a rather absurd and meaningless definition, however.

I can't think of any philosophical movement that uses such an meaningless definition of "existence". However, there are philosophical movements who believe that everything that does exist is inherently absurd and void of meaning.

Examples of such movements would be [Existentialists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existentialism) and [Discordians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discordianism) in the West and the absurdist schools of [Taoism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taoism) & [Zen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen) in the East!

Comment: I feel you're judging Taoism and Zen on the basis of not understanding their definition of existence. These people are not fools.

Comment: @PeterJ : I'm not arguing they are fools. Quite the contrary, actually! I consider myself an existentialist and strongly relate with the existential relativism so common in Eastern schools and so very lacking in most Western schools of thought. So, instead of mocking Taoism and Zen, I guess I'm recommending them! Anyway, where would you say I'm misinterpreting Taoism and Zen?

Comment: Pardon me. I may have been heavy-handed. Taoism and Zen do not state 'everything that does exist is inherently absurd and devoid of meaning'. They state that for an ultimate analysis nothing really exists, albeit that what seems to exist is meaningful and a part of reality. For a fundamental analysis they must be reduced. Our usual idea of existence would be wrong - hence we find it logically absurd and cannot explain it. (Cf. the doctrine of dependent-existence). What is real would be independent and would transcend the existence/non-existence distinction.

Comment: @PeterJ : "According to both Zen and Taoism, the attempted control of nature by man is at once absurd and useless" → http://artsites.ucsc.edu/faculty/lieberman/zen.html

Comment: I'm not sure why this comment is relevant. Both Zen and Taoism advocate abandoning the hubris that leads us to try and control the world.

Comment: @PeterJ : What Taoists, Zen Buddhists, Existentialists and Discordians all share, is both a celebration of authenticity and simplicity and a search for meaning in that celebration in what's a rather ironic and often absurd universe that is lacking inherent meaning.

Comment: Hmm. I would say they search for truth rather than meaning and that they celebrate a world that is lacking inherent existence. I would also never liken Buddhism and Taoism to Existentialism. (I don't know what Discordianism is but it sounds fun). I can agree with you up to a point. The inherent existence of the world is an absurd ideas on analysis, as metaphysicians are all too aware. But I don't gain the impression that your grasp of Buddhism and Taoism is total, and I feel you do them a disservice here. No big deal. .   . .

Answer (score 0):

In the second century BCE Nagarjuna proved that nothing really exists and nothing ever really happens. This is the claim of Middle Way Buddhism and phrased in one way or another is the claim of the Perennial philosophy.

This is not nihilism but the claim that all division and distinction is unreal or reducible in metaphysics. To exist is to 'stand out', thus for something to exist there must be a background from which it stands out. This is two things, and a fundamental theory must reduce them.As Schrodinger points out, as well as what appears to exist there is the 'canvas on which they are painted'.

For the mystic the world reduces to the 'I Am' of pure awareness, which is rather like Kant's 'thing-in-itself'. This would transcend the distinction between existence and non-existence such that we cannot say it exclusively exists or does not. Hence the qualifier 'really' in 'nothing really exists'. This explains Heraclitus' curious statement 'We are and are-not'.

The logical impossibility of explaining why there is anything at all undermines the very idea that there is anything at all. Once we reify even one thing we cannot solve the metaphysical problems that arise, and this should tell us something.